# xltabular row separation too big

Tags: xltabular

I have the following table constructed with xltabular. It stretches over many pages and it text-wraps the middle column. Both these features I would like to maintain and therefore **xltabular** has been great. But, the spacing between the rows are to big for my liking.

I tried **\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}** but it does not decrease the row separation for the wrapped text. This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X>{\hsize=1\hsize}X}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHS categories}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Indicator variable}} \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{GHS categories}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Indicator variable}} \\ \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

\texttt{EDU\_CAL}      & Proficiency in calculating / working out change         & \texttt{edu\_calc\_prof}    \\
\texttt{EDU\_RDSN}     & Proficiency in reading road signs                       & \texttt{edu\_rdsn\_prof}    \\
\texttt{EDU\_RSNN}     & Currently not attending an educational institution due to  & \texttt{edu\_rsnn\_phys}    \\
                       & physical limitations                                      &                                \\
                       & Currently not attending due to school disruptive factors & \texttt{edu\_rsnn\_school}  \\
                       & Currently not attending due to other commitments         & \texttt{edu\_rsnn\_commit}  \\
\texttt{EDU\_MODE\_TR} & Public transport is used to get to the educational institution & \texttt{edu\_public\_transport} \\
                       & Respondent walks to get to the educational institution  & \texttt{edu\_walk\_transport} \\
                       & Private transport is used to get to the educational institution & \texttt{edu\_priv\_transport} \\
\texttt{EDU\_TIME}     & Travel time to educational institution is more than an hour & \texttt{edu\_trans\_time\_more\_hour} \\
                       & Travel time to educational institution is less than an hour & \texttt{edu\_trans\_time\_less\_hour} \\
\texttt{EDU\_NEAREST}  & This educational institution is the nearest to the dwelling & \texttt{edu\_nearest\_inst} \\
\texttt{EDU\_NOT\_NEAR} & School factors being the reason the nearest educational & \texttt{edu\_school\_fac\_not\_near} \\
                       & institution is not attended                              &                            \\
                       & Academic conditions being the reason the nearest        & \texttt{edu\_aca\_cond\_not\_near} \\
                       & educational institution is not attended                 &                            \\
                       & Educational environment being the reason the nearest    & \texttt{edu\_edu\_env\_not\_near} \\
                       & educational institution is not attended                 &                            \\
                       & Admission availability being the reason the nearest     & \texttt{edu\_admission\_avail\_not\_near} \\
                       & educational institution is not attended                 &                            \\
\texttt{EDU\_TOT\_FEES} & Total amount of tuition fees paid is less than R1000 for & \texttt{edu\_fees\_low} \\
                       & the year                                                 &                            \\
                       & Total amount of tuition fees paid is between R1000 and  & \texttt{edu\_fees\_med} \\
                       & R12000 for the year                                      &                            \\
                       & Total amount of tuition fees paid is between R12000 and & \texttt{edu\_fees\_high} \\
                       & R20000 for the year                                      &                            \\
                       & No tuition fees paid for the year                        & \texttt{edu\_fees\_none}    \\
\texttt{EDU\_NO\_FEES} & Not paying fees due to financial status                 & \texttt{edu\_fin\_status\_fees} \\
                       & Not paying fees due to receiving financial support      & \texttt{edu\_fin\_support\_no\_fees} \\
\texttt{EDU\_BURS}     & Benefited from financial help, fee reduction or partial  & \texttt{edu\_bursary} \\
                       & bursary                                                  &                            \\
\texttt{EDU\_PROB\_BOOK} & Lack of books / learning materials                      & \texttt{edu\_book}          \\
\texttt{EDU\_PROB\_POOR} & Poor quality of teaching / lecturing                    & \texttt{edu\_poor\_teach\_qual} \\
\texttt{EDU\_PROB\_LACK} & Lack of teachers                                        & \texttt{edu\_lack\_teachers} \\
\texttt{EDU\_PROB\_BAD\_C} & Facilities in bad condition                             & \texttt{edu\_fac\_bad\_cond} \\
\texttt{EDU\_PROB\_FEES} & Fees too high                                            & \texttt{edu\_fees\_high} \\
\texttt{EDU\_PROB\_CLAS} & Classes too large / too many learners                    & \texttt{edu\_class\_large} \\
                       & Teachers/lecturers are often absent from school         & \texttt{edu\_teach\_abs} \\
                       & Teachers/lecturers were involved in a strike            & \texttt{edu\_teach\_strike} \\
\texttt{EDU\_FOOD}     & School feeding scheme / government nutrition programme  & \texttt{edu\_food\_school} \\
\texttt{EDU\_VLNC}     & Victim of any violence, corporal punishment, or verbal  & \texttt{edu\_violence} \\
                       & abuse at school                                          &                            \\
\texttt{EDU\_ABS}      & Absent from school during past school week               & \texttt{edu\_absent}        \\
\texttt{EDU\_ABSRSN}   & Personal reasons for absenteeism                         & \texttt{edu\_personal\_rsn\_absent} \\
                       & External reasons for absenteeism                         & \texttt{edu\_external\_rsn\_absent} \\
                       & School factors reason for absenteeism                    & \texttt{edu\_school\_rsn\_absent} \\ \hline

\end{xltabular}
```

Comment: Please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/3929 for details). Here we have to add stuff in order to test your code and the stuff we add might not be the same as you have.

Comment: why have you split paragraphs of text up on to separate rows of the table? columns 2 and 3 are X columns so they would automatically linebreak text to the calculated width.

Comment: it looks like you should make col 1 and 3 `l` columns so they are natural width and make column 2 an `X`  with no `\hsize` changes)

Answer (score 2):

I propose a different layout: some of the variable indicators are very long and so it's difficult to keep a reasonable width for the GHS category column. My suggestion is to put the variable indicator on top of the category description, with some horizontal space to make it a bit more prominent.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next instruction
\catcode`_=12

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l >{\hangindent=1em \hangafter=1 }X @{}}
 
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
\toprule 
\textnormal{Variable name} & Indicator variable and GHS category \\
\midrule 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\tablename\ \thetable, continued from previous page} \\
\addlinespace[\abovecaptionskip]
\toprule 
\textnormal{Variable name} & Indicator variable and GHS category \\
\midrule 
\endhead

\midrule \multicolumn{2}{@{}r@{}}{\footnotesize\itshape continued on next page} \\ 
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

EDU_CAL 
& \texttt{edu_calc_prof} \newline
  Proficiency in calculating\slash working out change \\*
\addlinespace
EDU_RDSN
& \texttt{edu_rdsn_prof} \newline
  Proficiency in reading road signs \\*
\addlinespace
EDU_RSNN 
& \texttt{edu_rsnn_phys} \newline
  Currently not attending an educational institution due to physical limitations \\*
& \texttt{edu_rsnn_school} \newline
  Currently not attending due to school disruptive factors \\*
& \texttt{edu_rsnn_commit} \newline
  Currently not attending due to other commitments \\
\addlinespace
EDU_MODE_TR 
& \texttt{edu_public_transport} \newline
  Public transport is used to get to the educational institution \\*
& \texttt{edu_walk_transport} \newline
  Respondent walks to get to the educational institution \\*
& \texttt{edu_priv_transport} \newline
  Private transport is used to get to the educational institution \\
\addlinespace
EDU_TIME 
& \texttt{edu_trans_time_more_hour} \newline
  Travel time to educational institution is more than an hour \\*
& \texttt{edu_trans_time_less_hour} \newline
  Travel time to educational institution is less than an hour \\
\addlinespace
EDU_NEAREST  
& \texttt{edu_nearest_inst} \newline
  This educational institution is the nearest to the dwelling \\
\addlinespace
EDU_NOT_NEAR 
& \texttt{edu_school_fac_not_near} \newline
  School factors being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended \\*
& \texttt{edu_aca_cond_not_near} \newline
  Academic conditions being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended \\*
& \texttt{edu_edu_env_not_near} \newline
  educational environment being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended \\*
& \texttt{edu_admission_avail_not_near} \newline
  Admission availability being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended \\
\addlinespace
EDU_TOT_FEES 
& \texttt{edu_fees_low} \newline
  Total amount of tuition fees paid is less than R1000 for the year \\*
& \texttt{edu_fees_med} \newline
  Total amount of tuition fees paid is between R1000 and R12000 for the year \\*
& \texttt{edu_fees_high} \newline
  Total amount of tuition fees paid is between R12000 and R20000 for the year \\*
& \texttt{edu_fees_none} \newline
  No tuition fees paid for the year \\
\addlinespace
EDU_NO_FEES 
& \texttt{edu_fin_status_fees} \newline
  Not paying fees due to financial status \\*
& \texttt{edu_fin_support_no_fees} \newline
  Not paying fees due to receiving financial support \\
\addlinespace
EDU_BURS
& \texttt{edu_bursary} \newline
  Benefited from financial help, fee reduction or partial bursary \\*
\addlinespace
EDU_PROB_BOOK 
& \texttt{edu_book} \newline
  Lack of books\slash learning materials \\
\addlinespace
EDU_PROB_POOR 
& \texttt{edu_poor_teach_qual} \newline
  Poor quality of teaching\slash lecturing \\
\addlinespace
EDU_PROB_LACK 
& \texttt{edu_lack_teachers} \newline
  Lack of teachers \\
\addlinespace
EDU_PROB_BAD_C 
& \texttt{edu_fac_bad_cond} \newline
  Facilities in bad condition \\
\addlinespace
EDU_PROB_FEES 
& \texttt{edu_fees_high} \newline
  Fees too high \\
\addlinespace
EDU_PROB_CLAS 
& \texttt{edu_class_large} \newline
  Classes too large\slash too many learners \\*
& \texttt{edu_teach_abs} \newline
  Teachers\slash lecturers are often absent from school \\*
& \texttt{edu_teach_strike} \newline
  Teachers\slash lecturers were involved in a strike \\
\addlinespace
EDU_FOOD
& \texttt{edu_food_school} \newline
  School feeding scheme\slash government nutrition programme \\
\addlinespace
EDU_VLNC
& \texttt{edu_violence} \newline
  Victim of any violence, corporal punishment, or verbal abuse at school \\
\addlinespace
EDU_ABS 
& \texttt{edu_absent} \newline
  Absent from school during past school week \\
\addlinespace
EDU_ABSRSN 
& \texttt{edu_personal_rsn_absent} \newline
  Personal reasons for absenteeism \\*
& \texttt{edu_external_rsn_absent} \newline
  External reasons for absenteeism \\*
& \texttt{edu_school_rsn_absent} \newline 
  School factors reason for absenteeism \\

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

With `` \catcode`_=12 `` (inside a group) we locally dispense with the need to type `\_`, making the code more readable.

Groups under the same (uppercase) variable are separated by some vertical space; with `\\*` we avoid uncanny page breaks in blocks referring to the same variable.

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg, this is a great suggestion and your code works well!

Answer (score 1):

No need to set `\arraystretch` to a value less than 1. For columns 1 and 3, I would (a) not allow automatic line breaking, and (b) automate the use of the monospaced font. I suggest using automatic hanging indentation of continued lines in row 2. I can't see a good reason for rendering the header lines in **bold-face**.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % limit the scope of the next instruction
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} 
 >{\ttfamily}l 
 >{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1}L 
 >{\ttfamily}l @{}}
 
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\
\toprule 
\textnormal{Variable name} & 
GHS categories & 
\textnormal{Indicator variable} \\ 
\midrule 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable, continued from previous page} \\
\addlinespace
\toprule 
\textnormal{Variable name} & 
GHS categories & 
\textnormal{Indicator variable} \\
\midrule 
\endhead

\midrule \multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{\footnotesize\itshape continued on next page} \\ 

\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

EDU\_CAL 
& Proficiency in calculating\slash working out change & edu\_calc\_prof \\
EDU\_RDSN
& Proficiency in reading road signs & edu\_rdsn\_prof \\
EDU\_RSNN 
& Currently not attending an educational institution due to physical limitations & edu\_rsnn\_phys \\
& Currently not attending due to school disruptive factors & edu\_rsnn\_school  \\
& Currently not attending due to other commitments & edu\_rsnn\_commit  \\
EDU\_MODE\_TR 
& Public transport is used to get to the educational institution & edu\_public\_transport \\
& Respondent walks to get to the educational institution & edu\_walk\_transport \\
& Private transport is used to get to the educational institution & edu\_priv\_transport \\
EDU\_TIME 
& Travel time to educational institution is more than an hour & edu\_trans\_time\_more\_hour \\
& Travel time to educational institution is less than an hour & edu\_trans\_time\_less\_hour \\
EDU\_NEAREST  
& This educational institution is the nearest to the dwelling & edu\_nearest\_inst \\
EDU\_NOT\_NEAR 
& School factors being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended & edu\_school\_fac\_not\_near \\
& Academic conditions being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended & edu\_aca\_cond\_not\_near \\
& Educational environment being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended & edu\_edu\_env\_not\_near \\
& Admission availability being the reason the nearest educational institution is not attended & edu\_admission\_avail\_not\_near \\
EDU\_TOT\_FEES 
& Total amount of tuition fees paid is less than R1000 for the year & edu\_fees\_low \\
& Total amount of tuition fees paid is between R1000 and R12000 for the year & edu\_fees\_med \\
& Total amount of tuition fees paid is between R12000 and R20000 for the year & edu\_fees\_high \\
& No tuition fees paid for the year & edu\_fees\_none \\
EDU\_NO\_FEES 
& Not paying fees due to financial status & edu\_fin\_status\_fees \\
& Not paying fees due to receiving financial support & edu\_fin\_support\_no\_fees \\
EDU\_BURS
& Benefited from financial help, fee reduction or partial bursary & edu\_bursary \\
EDU\_PROB\_BOOK 
& Lack of books\slash learning materials & edu\_book \\
EDU\_PROB\_POOR 
& Poor quality of teaching\slash lecturing & edu\_poor\_teach\_qual \\
EDU\_PROB\_LACK 
& Lack of teachers & edu\_lack\_teachers \\
EDU\_PROB\_BAD\_C 
& Facilities in bad condition & edu\_fac\_bad\_cond \\
EDU\_PROB\_FEES 
& Fees too high & edu\_fees\_high \\
EDU\_PROB\_CLAS 
& Classes too large\slash too many learners & edu\_class\_large \\
& Teachers\slash lecturers are often absent from school & edu\_teach\_abs \\
& Teachers\slash lecturers were involved in a strike & edu\_teach\_strike \\
EDU\_FOOD
& School feeding scheme\slash government nutrition programme & edu\_food\_school \\
EDU\_VLNC
& Victim of any violence, corporal punishment, or verbal abuse at school & edu\_violence \\
EDU\_ABS 
& Absent from school during past school week & edu\_absent \\
EDU\_ABSRSN 
& Personal reasons for absenteeism & edu\_personal\_rsn\_absent \\
& External reasons for absenteeism & edu\_external\_rsn\_absent \\
& School factors reason for absenteeism & edu\_school\_rsn\_absent \\ 

\end{xltabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico for your help, this works perfectly. You are a legend!